# How do you say "chunky" or "congealed" in Japanese?

Tags: words, food

Couldn't find this one in my dictionaries.  How would you translate "chunky" into Japanese?  As in chunky peanut butter, or, "I left the milk out for 3 days and now it's all chunky," or, "the chemicals congealed into a kind of chunky gel".

Comment: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=chunky

Comment: I don't think posting a generic link is the most considerate. For example, in your link it says chunky peanut butter is 「ピーナッツフレーク入りのピーナッツバター」 and that's not the best example..I would agree that in this context, like snailboat says, 粒入り would be best suited.

Comment: Also, just like any language, you can't really carry over meanings like that. So the Japanese for chunky peanut butter is not the same as chunky rotten milk. You need to always single out context.

Comment: I'm assuming by submitting that link as a comment rather than an answer, Darius was intending to communicate something along the lines of, "here's a reference that seems to address this question but I cannot verify its accuracy."

Comment: At least I know how to say "[chunky bacon](http://kakutani.com/20080213.html#p02)"...

Comment: 「厚切りベーコン」 - awesome!  Added to my vocab deck :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peanut butter:「[粒入]{つぶい}り（の）」、「つぶつぶ（の）」, etc.

Rotten milk:「ドロドロになる/なっている」、「ドロドロの」, etc.

Chunky gel: same as rotten milk.  If it is very hard, one could use 「ゴツゴツ」、「ゴロゴロ」, etc.

I only trust you can change these forms freely according to the context.